# Code design advice

Tags: c#, extension-methods, structuremap

I use an structuremap in my project and quite often I get stuck in an extension method where I need an instance of some object.

the first method is to send my repository into the extension method and the other method is to have a static repository and initialize it inside my method like this.

```
public static class SomeExtensions {
    static IRepository _repository;
    public static string ExtensionsMethod1(this HtmlHelper helper) {
        _repository = ObjectFactory.GetIntance<IRepository>();
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

what is best to do in this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really answering the question, just this specific code snippet:

You shouldn't use a repository in your ASP.NET MVC custom html helper methods. This is the controller's responsibility to manipulate the model. Html helper methods are for generating small HTML snippets.

As far as the more general case is concerned, then well, extension methods are just syntactic sugar for plain static methods so you can't inject dependencies into them.

Comment: In this specific case I'm rendering a navigation menu so I need to fetch all children, descendants and so for each item, Maybe its more appropriate to send a complete hierarchical object to the view instead?

Comment: @Marcus: Yes build the view model in the controller, don't have html helpers referencing repositories.